# What are all the group endomorphisms of the circle group?

Tags: group-theory

The circle group is the unit circle in the complex plane under multiplication. What are all the group endomorphisms of this group? (I can think of $z\mapsto z^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: I believe that's it.

Comment: $z\mapsto\bar{z}$

Comment: $\bar{z}=z^{-1}$ for $\|z\|=1$ right?

Comment: Oh, that's right.

Comment: @DanielRust As far as the continuous ones are concerned, yes. I expect there are discontinuous ones, however.

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't even consider that there might be discontinuous homomorphisms on this group, thanks.

Comment: One would think that the answer might then depend on the axiom of choice. Strange things happen with uncountably generated groups and the axiom of choice. For instance AoC implies $(\mathbb{R},+)\cong(\mathbb{C},+)$.

Comment: If we choose a Hamel basis $\{1\}\cup\{u_{\lambda}\mid \lambda\in\Lambda\}$ for $\mathbb{R}$ and then define $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(1)=1$ and $f(u_{\lambda})=0$, then compose $f$ with the exponential map, do we get a map $\exp\circ f\colon\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ which induces a non-trivial map $g\colon S^1\to S^1$ such that $g\circ\exp=\exp\circ f$? This seems plausible, and the image of $g$ would be a dense, proper subset of $S^1$.

Comment: The above is wrong because $f$ isn't $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, so isn't a group homomorphism. A similar idea will follow through though I think. Pick some non-continuous endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ (for instance $f(u_{\lambda})=u_{g(\lambda)}$ for some function $g\colon \Lambda\to\Lambda$) and force it to induce one on its quotient. I'll think more on this.

Comment: Some more "discontinuous ones": you can separate the torsion and torsion free part to obtain a decomposition of the form $\mathbb{Q}^{(\mathfrak{c})}\oplus \bigoplus_{p \in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ and you can define endomorphisms "component by component". In particular, any collection $(n_p)_{p \in \mathbb{P}},$ where each $n_p$ is a $p$-adic integer, gives rise to a unique endomorphism which fixes all elements of infinite order (to maintain some sense of "constructiveness", I will not mention the vast amount of endomorphisms of the torsion-free part).

Comment: @PavelC Is there a reason the torsion exact sequence splits?

Comment: @DanielRust All the summands are divisible groups, i.e. injective $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, inside the unit group which is also divisible, i.e. injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module. More genrally, every divisible group has a decomposition of this form (i.e. some summands $\mathbb{Q}$ and some summands $\mathbb{Z}_{p^\infty}$).

Comment: (Everything here is modulo $1$) I must be missing something. Presumably for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, the elements $\pi$ and $q-\pi$ are not torsion elements, so one of the above homomorphisms can fix them and, presumably, also be able to map $q$ to a different element, but $f(q)=f(\pi+q-\pi)=f(\pi)+f(q-\pi)=\pi + q-\pi=q$. What am I missing?

Comment: @DanielRust: You are not missing anything, it was rushed from me to say it fixes all torsion-free elements. However, it fixes continuum many of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a large ring. In general, recall that if $G$ is a locally compact (Hausdorff) abelian group then $\text{Hom}(G, S^1)$ is the Pontryagin dual of $G$. Hence $\text{Hom}((S^1)_{\delta}, S^1)$, where $(S^1)_{\delta}$ denotes $S^1$ with the discrete topology, is the Pontryagin dual of $(S^1)_{\delta}$. Like the Pontryagin dual of any discrete group, it must be compact, and hence must be much larger than $\mathbb{Z}$. In fact it is precisely the [Bohr compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_compactification) of $\mathbb{Z}$.

To get an idea of how large the Bohr compactification of $\mathbb{Z}$ has to be, some manipulations involving Pontryagin duality show that it is the free compact (Hausdorff) abelian group on one generator. In particular, there is a natural map from it to the profinite integers which I believe splits (as a map of abelian groups, at least) as described by PavelC in the comments.